# Nonlinear functional equation with tangent

Tags: functional-equations

Please help me with this. I need to find a non-trivial function $g(x)$ which satisfy the following functional equation
$$\tan(g(x))+g(x)+g(x)\tan^2(g(x))=0$$

Comment: This is _not_ a functional equation.

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong. This is a functional equation.

Comment: OK, this is a functional equation _in name only_. Imagine a simple algebraic equation, like $x^3-3x^2-3x+1=0$. It is definitely not a functional equation, for there is no unknown function of any sort, is it? Now suppose that we rewrite this equation and substitute every single instance of $x$ with $f(t)$. Does this make it a functional equation? Technically yes, but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no non-trivial real (I assume you meant real as you didn't specify anything else) solution. We can rewrite your equation (using the usual trigonometric identities) as

$$g(x) = - \frac{\tan(g(x))}{1+\tan^2(g(x))} = -\frac{1}{2} \sin(2 g(x))$$

If there is some $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $a := g(x_0) \neq 0$ then we have

$$a = - \frac{1}{2} \sin(2 a)$$

which is equivalent to $-2a = \sin(2a)$ which has the only real solution $a=0$. Therefore $g(x_0)=0$ and therefore $g(x) = 0$ for all $x$.